# Autosizing Subview iOS6/iOS7

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, autosize

I have a problem using Autosizing and i hope that you can help me.

I have an UINavigationController (nav) and a button that allows me to push an UIViewController (master controller).

The master controller is a freeform controller in my storyboard that i get using its storyboard ID. It contains the main view(master view) whith three subviews : subA, subB and subC.

[image]

I fixed the autoSizing of my masterView like this : [image]

And for the subviews :

1. SubA :[image]
2. SubB :[image]
3. SubC : [image]

When i launch the application on iphone 4" and 3.5" on iOS6, all the elements are fixed in the perfect place and with perfect sizes -> No problem !

**On iOS7**, subA are fine but the height of subB is larger than expected : 
[image]

I expect to have the **sub a** always on top with same height, the **sub c** always on bottom with same height and the **sub b** with flexible height.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: do you have problem on screen size 4" on ios6 & ios7 ? If yes it is because you've choosen flexible height for "sub B" (try removing inner solid bi-directional arrow for "sub B").   What's your expected result ?

Comment: THe problem is on iOS7, I expect to have the sub a always on top with same height, the sub c always on bottom with same height and the sub b with flexible height.

Comment: on both 3.5" and 4" screens ?

Comment: Yes, because I want to keep the height of sub a and c but the sub b can be slightly small

Comment: have you tried fixing masterview's top & bottom height from container?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't works :/ Should i use autolayout with constraints to solve the problem ?